# I want to implement a cache storage on my powershell for quicker runtime on next run

Tags: powershell, caching, parallel-processing, local-storage

I am a powershell beginner and self learner. I finally made my script to get AD Users from NestedGroup. I now want to make a cache for them to make a quicker result when I run the script on the second time. I am totally lost on what I am doing and I want to ask for some approach from professionals here. Thank you for guidance.

Here is my code.

```
function Get-CachedGroupMembership($groupname){
    $groupName = "cached_$($groupName)"
    $cachedResults = Get-Variable -Scope Global -Name $groupName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if($null -ne $cachedResults){
     "found cached result"
     $existing = write-host "Check: i found existing"
     return $cachedResults,  $existing
    }
    else{
     $searching = write-host "Check: Searching"
     $results = get-adgroup $groupname -properties memberof, members
     Set-CachedGroupMembership -groupName $groupName -value $results
     
     return $searching
    }
 }

 Function Set-CachedGroupMembership($groupName,$value){
    Set-Variable -Scope Global -Name $groupName -Value $value
    return $value
}
  function Get-ADUsers_cached { 
    param ( 
        [Parameter(ValuefromPipeline = $true, mandatory = $true)][String] $GroupName
    ) 
    [int]$circular = $null

    # result holder
    $resultHolder = @()
        $table = $null 
        $nestedmembers = $null 
        $adgroupname = $null     

        # get members of the group and member of
        # $ADGroupname = get-adgroup $groupname -properties memberof, members
        $ADGroupname = Get-CachedGroupMembership -GroupName $groupName 

        # list all members as list (no headers) and save to var
        $memberof = $adgroupname | select -expand memberof 
       
        if ($adgroupname) {  
            if ($circular) { 
                $nestedMembers = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $GroupName -recursive 
                $circular = $null 
            } 
            else { 
                $nestedMembers = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $GroupName | sort objectclass -Descending
                # if get adgroupmember returns nothing, it uses the members for ordinary getADGroup
                if (!($nestedmembers)) {
                    $unknown = $ADGroupname |select -expand members
                    if ($unknown) {
                        $nestedmembers = @()
                        foreach ($member in $unknown) {
                            $nestedmembers += get-adobject $member
                        }
                    }
                }
            } 
            # loops through each member
            ForEach($nestedmember in $nestedmembers){ 
                # creates the properties into a custom object. 
                $Props = @{
                    Type            = $nestedmember.objectclass;
                    Name            = $nestedmember.name;
                    DisplayName     = "";
                    ParentGroup     = $ADgroupname.name;
                    Enabled         = "";
                    Nesting         = $nesting;
                    DN              = $nestedmember.distinguishedname;
                    Comment         = ""
                    EmployeeNumber  = "";
                    LastLogonDate   = "";
                    PasswordLastSet = "";
                } 
                # if member object is a user
                if ($nestedmember.objectclass -eq "user") { 
                    # saves all the properties in the table. 
                    $nestedADMember = get-aduser $nestedmember.Name -properties enabled, displayname, EmployeeNumber, LastLogonDate, PasswordLastSet
                    $table = new-object psobject -property $props 
                    $table.enabled = $nestedadmember.enabled
                    $table.name = $nestedadmember.samaccountname
                    $table.displayname = $nestedadmember.displayname
                    $table.EmployeeNumber = $nestedadmember.EmployeeNumber
                    $table.LastLogonDate = $nestedadmember.LastLogonDate
                    $table.PasswordLastSet = $nestedadmember.PasswordLastSet

                    #save all in 1 storage
                    $resultHOlder += $table | select type, name, displayname, parentgroup, nesting, enabled, dn, comment , EmployeeNumber, LastLogonDate, PasswordLastSet
                } 


                # if member object is group
                elseif ($nestedmember.objectclass -eq "group") {  
                    $table = new-object psobject -Property $props 
                    # if circular, meaning the groups member of list contains one of its members. 
                    # e.g. if group 2 is a member of group 1 and group 1 is a member of grou 2
                    if ($memberof -contains $nestedmember.distinguishedname) { 
                        $table.comment = "Circular membership" 
                        $circular = 1 
                    } 
                    # for circular output
                    #$table | select type, name, displayname, parentgroup, nesting, enabled, dn, comment 
                    #calling function itself
                    $resultHOlder += Get-ADUsers_cached -GroupName $nestedmember.distinguishedName                             
                } 
                else { 
                    if ($nestedmember) {
                        $table = new-object psobject -property $props
                        $resultHolder += $table | select type, name, displayname, parentgroup, nesting, enabled, dn, comment, EmployeeNumber, LastLogonDate, PasswordLastSet
                    }
                } 
            } 
        } 



    return   $resultHOlder 

}
function Get-NestedGroupUsers_cached {
    param ( 
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][String]$FileName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][String]$searchFileURL
    )
    $storageHolder = @()
    $groupList = Get-Content $searchFileURL 
    $groupList |  ForEach-Object { 
        $allusers = Get-ADUsers_cached -GroupName $_
        $storageHolder += $allusers  
       
    }
    $storageHolder | select ParentGroup, Name, EmployeeNumber, Enabled, LastLogonDate, PasswordLastSet  |Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\***\Desktop\$FileName.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Force
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of a global or module scoped variable to store the info.  Then, check for the presence of the variable on second execution and pull from that, if present.

For instance, your query of AD Groups would be a good one to cache.

I would make two functions to make this easier:

```
function Get-CachedGroupMembership($groupname){
   $groupName = "cached_$($groupName)"
   $cachedResults = Get-Variable -Scope Global -Name $groupName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
   if($null -ne $cachedResults){
    "found cached result"
    return $cachedResults
   }
   else{
    "need to cache"
    $results = get-adgroup $groupname -properties memberof, members
    Set-CachedGroupMembership -groupName $groupName -value $results
   }
}
```

Then to cache the results, I'd use this function too.

```
Function Set-CachedGroupMembership($groupName,$value){
    Set-Variable -Scope Global -Name $groupName -Value $value
    return $value
}
```

Finally, replace the call to `$ADGroupname = get-adgroup $groupname -properties memberof, members` with a call to `Get-CachedGroupMembership -GroupName $groupName`.

If you really want to persist the cache, you could even write results out to JSON and modify these functions to retrieve them, but then you could have an issue with stale results.  So, you should always leave a way to force an update to the cache, for instance you could modify these functions to add a `-Force` switch to update your cached value.

With a little copy and paste, you could modify these functions into `Get-CachedADUser` as well, and have your entire script caching results.

Comment: Hello FoxDeploy, Thank you so much for the solution that you give. I tried to use this solution and I am wonder on this line of code

$groupName = "cached_$($groupName)"

I got this error: 
Get-ADGroup: Cannot find an object with identity: 'cached_NAMEOFTHEGROUP'

Comment: 1. Make sure you add both functions to your script. 2. run the functions before the main body of your code.  3.  Can you edit your post to now include your complete code?

Comment: I made it work right now with that script Thank you so much and I understand how it works now. I update my code now you can take a look. i cant just post the ParentGroup on excel it show the path like this on CSV
cached_CN=ADM-GISMgSrvAdmins,OU=ADM,OU=GG,OU=Groups,OU=Global,DC=oneabbott,DC=com

Comment: Also, is there any way to cached the all old result of the function Get-NestedGroupUsers_cached? Then call that condition if exist while running the Get-ADUsers_cached function?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do.  Maybe better to ask a new question to help you get going.